# C++ issue with conversion of std::string to std::wstring - Windows vs Linux

Tags: c++, string, std, wstring

I'm trying to convert the string `"pokémon"` from std::string to std::wstring using

`std::wstring wsTmp(str.begin(), str.end());`

This works on Windows, but on Linux it returns `"pok\xffffffc3\xffffffa9mon"`

How can I make it work on Linux?

Comment: C++ isn't great with diffrent character encodings.  getting a dedicated library can be very helpful.

Comment: *"This works on Windows*" - no, it doesn't, actually. All that constructor does is copy each `char` as-is to `wchar_t`, extending the value from 8bits to 16bits on Windows or 32bits on Posix. There is no encoding conversion performed. What is the actual encoding of the `std::string`? ANSI (system locale)? UTF-8? It makes a BIG difference in how the data needs to be converted to `std::wstring` *properly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on POSIX.

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    
    std::string a = "pokémon";
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> cv;
    std::wstring wide = cv.from_bytes(a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The `wstring` holds the correct string at the end.

Important note by @NathanOliver: `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` was deprecated in C++17 and may be removed from the standard in a future version.

Comment: Do note that `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` was deprecated in C++17 and may be removed from the standard in a future version.

Comment: I will add this to my answer. Thank you. OP did not specify a C++ version though...

Comment: This example will work correctly only if the `.cpp` file is saved as UTF-8, and the compiler parses the file as UTF-8. Consider using the `u8` prefix on the string literal to force it to UTF-8, even if the file is not using UTF-8, eg: `std::string a = u8"pokémon";` But whatever charset the `.cpp` is actually encoded in, make sure the compile is setup to interpret the file in that same charset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you seem to be running into here is that it's treating the `é`'s two code units as separate code points when converting. There's no good way to do this with the standard library past C++17, as `std::wstring_convert` was deprecated without being given a proper replacement. You have several options, none of them great:

1. Use the deprecated `std::wstring_convert` and ignore the deprecation warnings and the fact that it may be removed in a future revision of C++.
2. Implement your own widening conversion routine (You could use [icu4c's BreakIterator](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/classicu_1_1BreakIterator.html) to assist with this).
3. Use a heavier library like [Boost.Locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) to do all the heavy lifting for you.

Also somewhat unrelated, but if you care about consistency across different platforms you should be using `std::u16string` or `std::u32string`. `std::wstring`'s character size depends on the size of `wchar_t`, which varies between different compilers and platforms.